# How can i get specific file name from all subdirectotires?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this variable called mainpath:

```
private void CreateMainDirectory()
        {
            mainpath = Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\newimages",
                   "Changed_Resolution_By_" + numeric.ToString());
            if (!Directory.Exists(mainpath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mainpath);
            }
        }
```

I create the mainpath and then later in my program i create many subdirectories inside the mainpath and in each subdirectory there are many files.
In each subdirectory there is also one file start with animated.
For example in the first subdirectory the file name is: animated2x2.gif
In the last sub directory the file name is animated502x502.gif

Now i have in my diesigner in a form a pictureBox1 and trackBar1.
What i want to do is to loop over all the subdirectories under mainpath get all the files start with animated. And then add the files to trackBar1 so when i move the trackBar1 left or right it will display/show the current animated file in the pictureBox1.

The animated files are all type gif. How can i make it ?

Comment: Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\newimages", "animated*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainPath, "animated*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will return a list of all files with animated in their file name in any directory under mainPath